Runs in Visual Studio but returns 404 error when deployed in IIS
Hi everyone I hope everyone and safe and doin’ well.
I just really need your help with an error I have been fixing for less than 2 weeks. I have created Asp Net Core Web-App, when I run it with IIS Express In V-Studio it runs well but when I deployed it into IIS I got 404 Status error from my Datatables.
Then when I open the Developer’s Tools on  Console and Network Tabs I found out the 404 error and I think that is the cuase of error (please see Images below)
Cause of error: Jquery.min.js
Console Tab
Datatable in my IIS
I am new in IIS Deployment, I really appreciate your help. Just let me knkw what should do.
Thanks,
Kart
I tried checking the Ajax Url and it seems nothing wrong. But i still need your suggestions.
I tried also checking on a browser if my Ajax returns a data and it did, it returned what data I expect.

Hi Kart, could you try to copy the jquery.min.js url from the 404 error message, after find the url like https://localhost:*/js/jquery.min.js, then we can try to copy the jquery.min.js file and paste it into wwwroot/js folder for testing.

Hi Jason, the Jquery.min.js is already in wwwroot folder.

And I also configured my IIS Account to access the jquery.min.js but still i got 404 error. :(

Hi Kart, may I know you are free now, if so please reply me quickly, the forum will generate a chatroom for us investigate this issue.

Hi Kart, please try to share the complete url (404 jquery.min.js) for me, thanks

Yup I am free now.
And here is the link: http://localhost:81/FXAccountStatement/GetA11FXAccountSent?_=1714720326461

Thanks for your reply, please share me the structure of your publish files. I mean I want to check what inside the wwwroot folder.

Hi here is the Inside of the wwwroot folder are css, identiy, js, lib folders.

The 404 url is wrong you shared me, I mean I want the jquery.min.js url, thanks

You can copy it in the browser developer tools, the blue link one, right click it and copy it.

Hi Jason, is it that? (The link below)
http://localhost:81/App/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-min-js?v=_×Uj-30JU5yEx]q6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej_m4

here is the Inside of the wwwroot folder are css, identiy, js, lib folders.  , there is no App folder inside the wwwroot. folder.

You also can share the screenshot for me, then I can help you to check it easily.

I was trying that, i paste the image of wwwroot screenshot to the comment section but nothing happened so i typed manully.

You can try to upload the screenshot in below answer area, then we can find the url, you can share the link with me directly.

Hi Jason noted, please this link https://i.sstatic.net/frkbCm6t.png

It's my pleasure, I am waiting for your update.

Ok, please copy the App folder from your project and paste into wwwroot folder(publish files)

Hi Jason copy, for a while..

Try to check the files via this link : http://localhost:81/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-min-js?v=_%C3%97Uj-30JU5yEx]q6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej_m4

https://i.sstatic.net/HllvWrgO.png
Hi Jason this is what happen when I copy the App to Wwwroot folder.

Ok, please don't copy it, check the updated url here  http://localhost:81/lib/jquery/dist/jquery-min-js?v=_%C3%97Uj-30JU5yEx]q6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej_m4

Is it working in your side ?

Ok let me try, wait..

you can copy and paste it in browser address bar directly.

Hi Jason, it didn't work in my end.

Okey, my fault, seems you are opening the wwwroot from the project, please try to open if from IIS Management Tool, find the site and right-click it, and click Explore.

Am I right? All the steps you are trying are in your project folder, not the IIS.

Actually, it is the folder deployed in IIS

Ok, please share me the contents of your App folder (screenshot)

One more thing, please search where is the jquery.min.js using , I need to check the code. Until now, I can confirm it's code issue.

https://i.sstatic.net/rEUlpUmk.png
https://i.sstatic.net/Al3VmB8J.png
https://i.sstatic.net/19x2Kzy3.png
https://i.sstatic.net/MjJhI4pB.png

Please check those links, the content of my App folder

Thanks for your effort. please search where is the jquery.min.js using , I need to check the code. Until now, I can confirm it's code issue.

Hi Kart, any update ?

I think that jquery is autogenerated from asp net core. I think that jquery is use to process the data from my controller.

Please share me the physical path like this https://i.sstatic.net/KnSxWtCG.png

Just now, I create a brand new sample and I found the jquery.min.js file is used in _Layout file. The path is Views/Shared/, and I need to check this  picture  https://i.sstatic.net/AJOluzU8.png

https://i.sstatic.net/xRCuSaiI.png
Here, check this one

Ok, the physical path is wrong, the correct path should be C:\Net8\Cerebrum\App.

You are missing \app, try it and let me know the result.

Thanks Jason it is working now! :)

Please allow me summarize all the comment as answer below, many thanks

I have been fixing this less than two weeks but the mistake is only the Path jaha

Ok sure Jason, go ahead :)

The root cause for this issue is using the wrong path.
The correct path should contains the project_name.dll and web.config files.
Then the asp.net core runtime can find the startup file.
